# In what proportion of patients does a DVT progress to a PE?

Tags: blood-clotting

It is well known that deep vein thrombosis (DVT) may increase a patient's risk of pulmonary embolism (PE).

Of the patients who develop DVT, what is the estimated proportion who go on to develop a PE?